# Copy entire columns including blank rows

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

```
  //Copy
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA');
  var sss = ss.getSheetByName('Stats');
  var range = sss.getRange(1,7,sss.getLastRow(),5);
  var data = range.getValues();

  //Main_Event 1
  var ts = SpreadsheetApp.openById('BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB');
  var tss = ts.getSheetByName('Main_Event');
  tss.getRange(1,1, data.length, data[0].length).setValues(data);
```

Current results:

| Sheet A | Sheet A | Sheet A | Sheet A | Sheet A |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| one | two | three | four | five |
| new values | new values | new values | new values | new values |
| new values | new values | new values | new values | new values |
|  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |

| Sheet B | Sheet B | Sheet B | Sheet B | Sheet B |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| one | two | three | four | five |
| new values | new values | new values | new values | new values |
| new values | new values | new values | new values | new values |
| old values | old values | old values | old values | old values |
| old values | old values | old values | old values | old values |

Expected result:

| Sheet B | Sheet B | Sheet B | Sheet B | Sheet B |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| one | two | three | four | five |
| new values | new values | new values | new values | new values |
| new values | new values | new values | new values | new values |
|  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |

Sheet A: columns are filled up to row 85 and up to row 1000 they are blank.

Sheet B: there are rows filled up to row 1000.

So when I'm going to copy the values from A to B, I want the blank rows to take the place of the filled rows, being exactly the same as sheet A.

But in my attempts the old values keep appearing from row 86 to 1000 and only the 85 rows filled in A that are modified in B.

What am I doing wrong in my attempt?

Additional information:

When I try to do this same thing using the same code but sending the values within the same ID sheet, it works perfectly modifying the column completely including the blank rows.

But when I try to do it using different ID sheets, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After more research I found the error!

When using `sss.getLastRow()` it only retrieves the values up to the last row that contains values.

To collect data up to the last row of columns it is necessary to use `sss.getMaxRows()`.

Old code:

```
var range = sss.getRange(1,7,sss.getLastRow(),5);
```

New code:

```
var range = sss.getRange(1,7,sss.getMaxRows(),5);
```

Comment: To make this be a reliable solution you should assure someway that the number of rows from ss always be larger than the rows from sss.

Comment: Hi @Rubén thanks for the comment, I didn't realize I put one ```s``` less (it was a typo when bringing to the question and to the answer), I've edited it!

Comment: Actually the comment is referring to the source and target sheets, the source should always have more than the target. Maybe this solution is good enough for your specific case but I don't think that it will work in all cases.

Comment: Hi @Rubén would you be willing to create a answear with this additional protection? The options that came to my mind made the code very slow until I was able to create the new additional blank values that will be added.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why this isn't working, but maybe as a workaround you could use clearContents() before pasting? https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#clearcontents. You can also clear the specific range.

Comment: Hi @NiekWaarbroek I thought about doing this, but as the trigger is activated every 5 minutes, if by chance an error occurs between cleaning and sending the new data, the spreadsheet will be without any value and that cannot happen. Anyway, thanks for your time and keep your answer (in case other people in the future can use as you indicated).

Answer (score 1):

#### I think this is what want but not sure

```
function funk1() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA');
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName('Stats');
  var rg = sh.getRange(1, 7, sh.getMaxRows(), 5);
  var vs = rg.getValues();
  var tsh = SpreadsheetApp.openById('BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB');
  var tsh = tsh.getSheetByName('Main_Event');
  tsh.getRange(tsh.getLastRow() + 1, 1, vs.length, vs[0].length).setValues(vs);
}
```

Comment: Hello @Cooper, actually the idea is not to add values (like append) of ```Sheet A``` after the last row of ```Sheet B```, but to make a faithful copy of the Columns of ```Sheet A``` on ```Sheet B```, in this case I resolved to do it like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72438849/11462274 but Rubén brought a important comment about the risk of ```Sheet B``` having more lines than ```Sheet A```, so there would be some old values stay, so if you're interested in creating an answer taking into account of his comment, that would be very useful and important for all!